# Measure retention in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a dataset containing information on students enrolled in an after-school program in the following format:

```
student_id  year group number
1   2009-10 1
2   2009-10 1
3   2009-10 2
4   2009-10 3
5   2009-10 3
1   2010-11 1
2   2010-11 2
3   2010-11 3
4   2010-11 2
5   2010-11 2
```

I want to measure retention for each group on a per-year basis.  I need to write some kind of loop statement that will look back at the previous year, compute a value of similar IDs for each group, and return a value divided by total numbers in that group.  I have sketched out code (which is probably inefficient/missing some steps) as follows?

```
for (i in levels(data$year)){
  if (i=="2009-10"){
    #no previous year to look for
    next
  }else{
    for(g in levels(data$group)){

    ##perhaps a plyr summarize function?

    #look for id in previous year for that group
    #compute count of identical ids
    #return value/length(group)
    }
  }
```

*edit*
after reading some suggestions, perhaps it would be simpler to use the ddply(transform) function.  is there a way to create an associative relationship between the year and group number?  the code would look something like this:

```
tracking=ddply(data,"student_id", transform, enroll.year1=1, enroll.year2=ifelse(criteria goes here,1,0), enroll.year3=ifelse(criteria goes here,1,0)
```

some sample output might look like this:

```
Year    Group   retention rate

2010-11 1   0.88
2011-12 1   0.8

2010-11 2   0.5
2011-12 2   0.6

2010-11 3   0.5
2011-12 3   0.5
```

has anyone solved a similar retention problem before?  I'm having difficulty conceptualizing the steps, let alone implementing in R.  any help would be greatly appreciated.
    *

Comment: Could you provide the output for the sample data? Maybe you could `split(data, data$group)` and `lapply` an `order` by year and use a "cumulative-y" function? I'm not sure I get what you're after

Comment: Is it always these two years? Is it always two years (regardless of their value)?

Comment: no, the years are 2009-10, 2010-11 and 2011-12

Comment: sketched out some sample output

Comment: So in your sample data, the fact the student 2 was in group 1 in 2009, and in group 2 in 2010, means that she was *not* retained???

Comment: exactly.  she stayed in the entire _program_, but not the _group_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I can think of involves a self-join shifting one year. I will be using `data.table` for the simplicity of both joining and the grouping required. I'll also be changing some names and the year format for convenience. I have saved your data in a `data.frame` called `dd`:

```
names(dd) <- c('id', 'year', 'group')
dd$year <- as.integer(substr(dd$year, 1, 4))

dd.prev <- dd
dd.prev$year <- dd.prev$year + 1   ## shifting year upwards so it matches the next year

require(data.table)
dd <- data.table(dd)
setkey(dd, group, year)

dd.prev <- data.table(dd.prev)
setkey(dd.prev, group, year)
setnames(dd.prev, 'id', 'id.prev')  ## changing variable name so it is distinct

extra.year <- max(dd$year) + 1  ## the shift generates an extra year
dd.prev <- dd.prev[!year==extra.year]  ## drop extra year as retention not defined

dd <- dd[dd.prev]   ## join data from previous year to current data

dd.all[, retention:=as.numeric(length(intersect(id, id.prev)) 
                               /length(unique(id.prev))), 
       by=list(year, id)]
```

That last bit computes the retention rate as you defined it: number of students who still remain from last year, `intersect(id, id.prev)`, divided by the total number of students last year, `unique(id.prev)`. With this data it only generates the retention for 2010, but with a longer series it would generate it for all years except the first.

#### UPDATE 1: Using `plyr`

```
names(dd) <- c('id', 'year', 'group')
dd$year <- as.integer(substr(dd$year, 1, 4))

dd.prev <- dd
dd.prev$year <- dd.prev$year + 1   ## shifting year upwards so it matches the next year
names(dd.prev)[1] <- 'id.prev'  ## changing variable name so it is distinct

extra.year <- max(dd$year) + 1  ## the shift generates an extra year
dd.prev <- dd.prev[dd.prev$year!=extra.year,]  ## drop extra year

dd <- merge(dd, dd.prev, all.y=TRUE)   ## join data from previous year to current data



require(plyr)
dd <- ddply(dd, .(group, year), summarize, 
             retention=length(intersect(id, id.prev)) 
                        /length(unique(id.prev)))
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: it definitely puts me on the right track.  I'm having trouble actually implementing this code, however.  Is there a way tosimplify this using the ddply summarize function somehow?

Comment: Sure. I've added a second method using `plyr`.

Comment: Thanks for the super thorough solution.  Unfortunately, I think my issues are a bit more basic than I thought (I'm new to R) so I'm going to ask a new question.  Thanks again for the well thought out solution.

Comment: You are welcome. It took some head scratching for me, but I am sure this trick (the self-join) is quite common for people who work with databases.